# how can I configure YII i18n feature to use gettext?

Tags: internationalization, yii

I installed the yii-web-start extension, it uses a database for message translation, but I need use gettext instead.

Where and how can I configure YII-i18n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up i18n in your config (protected/config/main.php) with [CGettextMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGettextMessageSource) to use gettext.

```
'components' => array(
    'messages' => array(
        'class' => 'CGettextMessageSource'
     )
 ),
```

By default, you should store your .po-files under protected/messages.

Comment: What is the naming convention for the po files? Directory structure?

Comment: @NathanH see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26947408/2482457
Excerpt from [CGettextMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGettextMessageSource):
All translations are saved under the basePath directory. Translations in one language are kept as MO or PO files under an individual subdirectory whose name is the language ID. The file name is specified via catalog property, which defaults to 'messages'.