# Using GetText with Yii

Tags: php, yii, internationalization, gettext

I was using Yii's *CPhpMessageSource* for message translations. BUt i don't want to use it for my new project. Because i'll give source files to a translator, and i don't want to give him .php files for translation. He isn't a developer and probably broke files' syntax :)

Because of this, i can use *gettext* for translation messages. So, i can give *.mo* , *.po* files and he can translate them with *PoEdit* app. This way is easier for him.

I'm using gettext first time. For *CPhpMessageSource* , i'm basically executing `yiic message` command and it's generating `protected/messages/lang/category.php` files. But for gettext, how can i create *.po* files? How can i point Yii for using that *.po* files?

There is a 'gettext' extension, but i couldn't understand. Isn't there in-built gettext support ? Why should i install that extension? I don't want to use 3th party extensions, if it's possible.

**ADDITIONAL**

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735670/how-can-i-configure-yii-i18n-feature-to-use-gettext) question and answer, but i don't have any idea about next step.

Comment: Maybe my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26947408/2482457) in another thread will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii has [CGettextMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGettextMessageSource) to deal with GetText, but `yiic message` it's only for CPhpMessageSource.

The extension does not use CGettextMessageSource, instead it uses php's built in [gettext](http://php.net/gettext), so that using the built in funcions such as [_() / gettext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php), a software like [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) can then scan the php files and generate the MO or PO files for you.