# Yii and PHP Gettext

Tags: yii, internationalization, gettext, poedit

I want to make my yii app multilanguage. To do this I want to use gettext (because its much simpler than yii messages).

To this I used [this yii extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/gettext/), I configured the PO files, I made the translations, etc.

The big problem: nothing happened. Nothing was translated.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: what do u thins, what could be the problem?

Comment: I just built it with this extension. I guess you already fixed your issue? Otherwise I could post you my solution.

Comment: I used the yii's message feature, but I think the PO solution is far more comfortable.

So could you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I can advice you this awesome multilanguage extension!

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tstranslation/

Answer (score 1):

To use gettext without any extension follow those steps. In `config/main.php` set yout target language like this:

```
'language' = 'ru',
```

Set `messages` component to use `CGettextMessageSource`:

```
'messages' => array(
    'class' => 'CGettextMessageSource',
),
```

Create `messages.po` file in `protected/messages/ru` folder (note: folder name is same as language code). If [poedit](http://poedit.net/) is used `messages.po` file must have appropriate headers. Example:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: FOO BAR 1.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2011-11-11 11:11+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Language: ru\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2;\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: utf-8\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _ngettext:1,2;t:1c,2\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: ../..\n"
```

Note `t:1c,2`. This means, that first parameter from function `Yii::app()` will be used as context (see [msgctx](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_mono/gettext.html#index-msgctxt)) and second as actual string to translate. Without this your i18n will not work!

Now just open `messages.po` in poedit → `Update` → do translations → `Save`.
And `messages.mo` file will be created and used by Yii.

For you language plurals string see [gettext help](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_mono/gettext.html#Translating-plural-forms).